# Replace shower faucet valve stems

Tags: shower, faucet, valve

My shower faucet is leaking. So I removed the handle to see what kind of stems they use. I haven't seen this kind of stems anywhere. Does anyone know what they are and how to replace them?

[image]

[image]

Comment: do you see any place that you can use a wrench?

Comment: No, I can't get a good grip. I feel that this has to be disassembled somehow and then take it out. I showed pictures to my local hardware store and they said they don't have any stem like this one. Looks like I have to call a pro on this one.

Comment: Looks like a void or a hole in the cylinder near the 4-oclock position.  Is there anything visible at that position?

Comment: try to rotate one of the chrome parts,

Comment: You are very likely going to need a new cartridge to stop the leak.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you Ed Beal. Yes, these are washer-less ceramic valves. I changed the cartridge and it was simple than I thought. Basically you remove the plate and turn the chrome sleeve counter clockwise to remove it. Then use a channel lock to loosen the cartridge by holding the edge of the cartridge and turning it counter clockwise. Installed a new cartridge and gave it a gentle tight snug. No more leaks and shower works very well.

Please see the pics I took.

This is the cartridge part number
[image: This is the cartridge part number]

After removing plate and sleeve
[image: After removing plate and sleeve]

After loosening the cartridge
[image: After loosening the cartridge]

Cartridge removed
[image: Cartridge removed]

Installed a new cartridge
[image: Installed a new cartridge]

Comment: Thanks for adding your answer; you should also mark whichever answer you think is best as "the" answer by checking the checkmark. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Answer (score 0):

That those are 1/4 turn or limited turn I would say they are washer-less valves.
I would look around the outside of the body of the valve to see if there is a set screw / grub screw holding the cartridge in place, if you can not find a screw look closely at the brass hex piece that is cut out for the stop. Is that threaded on the outside if so it may unscrew or be a packing I am not sure but that is a possibility.
If it is a packing the clip and stop will probably need to be removed to unscrew and not damage the cartridge. Replacement o rings should be easy to find once you get it apart.